# Ajax call for autocomplete reference field

Tags: ajax, paragraphs

I do not succeed to fire the ajax when an autocomplete reference field widget is populated or changed inside a paragraph form.

**TO BE MORE CLEAR:** I Succeed when using a simple select list but not when using an autocomplete widget

**Edit to add**: I am not quite sure this is a paragraphs problem... I added this information to make sure I provided all the key elements.

If the Ajax callback is called, it should adapt the #options of a select field depending on what is selected in the autocomplete field.

**Note**: there are many paragraphs of this type in the main form (many autocomplete field with their select field)

Here is my code:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context)
{
    if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'my_paragraphs_type') {
        //I have also tried with ['my_autocomplete_ref_field']['widget']['#ajax'] 
        $element['subform']['my_autocomplete_ref_field']['widget']['target_id']['#ajax'] = [
            'callback' => 'ajx_rebuild_parag',
            'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
            //easy way to get the paragraph's form wrapper #id
            'wrapper' => 'my_parent_field' . $context['delta'] . '-item-wrapper' 
        ];
        $options = [];
        if (isset($element['subform']['my_autocomplete_ref_field']['widget']['0']['target_id']['#default_value'])) {
            $value = $element['subform']['my_autocomplete_ref_field']['widget']['0']['target_id']['#default_value'];
            $options=... //logic to construct the options according to $value
         }
        $element['subform']['my_select_field']['widget']['#options']=$options;
     }
}

//This callback works well if the Ajaxified widget is a select list
function ajx_rebuild_parag(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
   $el=$form_state->getTriggeringElement();
   $delta=$el['#field_parents'][1];
   $form_state->setRebuild(true);
   return $form['trigger_parent_field']['widget'][$delta]; 
}
```

=>Nothing happends when I select something with the autocomplete fieldd

Comment: You're setting the options back to `my_select_field`, shouldn't that be `my_autocomplete_ref_field`? I suggest you move the field name to a variable.

Comment: This is the purpose of this code: changing the #options of a field according to the values of another field. This code is working well when this "another field" is a select list but not when it is an autocomplete reference field widget.

Comment: Have you tried with `autocompletechange`  as the triggering event?

Comment: Yes I have tried, but to make sure I will retest and let you know

Comment: I succeed using autocompleteclose and autocompletechange (autocompletechange fits my needs) outside of a paragraphs... I will try inside now